# Sort array by custom function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am using only Javascript.

I have the following string :

```
?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice
```

What I need to do, is have the following outcome :

```
age:12|name:alice
```

I thought of a way to do this, it is the following :

```js
var str = "?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice";
var strSplit = str.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) { 
   console.log(strSplit[i]);
}
```

This returns the following result :

```
?pn1=age
pn2=name
pv1=12
pv2=alice
```

Since I want to join together **pn1** and **pv1** and **pn2** and **pv2**, the number present in the end of the string is important.

?pn**1**=age
pn**2**=name
pv**1**=12
pv**2**=alice

So I thought a way to do this is to sort the array by this number. and then joining every 2 values together after sorting.

I tried the following code :

```
 strSplit.sort(function() {
    var pref = strSplit[i].split('=')[0];
    return pref.charAt(pref.length-1);
});
```

It does not seem to work

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are the parameters always named as `pnX` and `pvX` (with `X` representing the number)?

Comment: @Martin yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the parts, collect all items and return a joined string.

```js
var string = '?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice',
    result = string
        .slice(1)
        .split('&')
        .reduce((r, p) => {
            var [k, value] = p.split('='),
                [key, index] = k.split(/(\d+)/);
            index--;
            r[index] = r[index] || {};
            r[index][key] = value;
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(({ pn, pv }) => [pn, pv].join(':'))
        .join('|');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in following steps.

- You can loop through half of the array and add corresponding keys and values to an array.
- Consider `i` is the current index when we loop through half array.
- The element at position `i` will be key.
- Add the half of the length and add it to `i` to get corresponding value.
- `split()` both key and value by `=` and get the second element.

```js
var str = "?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice";
var arr = str.split("&");
let half = arr.length/2
let res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < half; i++) { 
   res.push(`${arr[i].split('=')[1]}:${arr[i + half].split('=')[1]}`);
}
console.log(res.join('|'))
```

Comment: According to my test case, yours seems to be the fastest solution : https://jsbench.me/2vjwhpyu2l/1

Comment: @tcj because the solution assumes that `pn` values are in the first half and `pn` and `pv` values in the same order (Not that anything wrong with it since OP's MCVE suggests it)

Answer (score 2):

- You could use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to convert the query string to a collection of key-value pair.
- Then loop through them to group the the `pv` and `pn` values based on the number.
- Separate the string and and number values using the regex: `(\D+)(\d+)`
- Loop through the `obj.pn` and get the corresponding `pv` value for the same number
- Join the resulting array with `|`

This works with `pn` and `pv` values in any random order

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams("?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice")

const obj = { pn: {}, pv: {} }

for (let [key, value] of searchParams) {
  const [, k, number] = key.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/)
  obj[k][number] = value
}

const output = Object.entries(obj.pn)
                    .map(([n, key]) => `${key}:${obj.pv[n]}`)
                    .join("|")

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to first split values on `&` and add it to take digit as key and place on object and then later place the respective values in desired format

```js
var str = "?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice".replace(/^\?/,'')

var strSplit = str.split("&");

let op = strSplit.reduce((op,inp) => {
  let [key,value] = inp.split('=')
  let digit = key.match(/\d+/)[0]
  op[digit] = op[digit] || []
  op[digit].push(value)
  return op
},{})

let final = Object.values(op).reduce((op,inp) => {
  let [key,value] = inp
  op.push(`${key}:${value}`)
  return op
} ,[]).join(' | ')

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert that `&` split to a string and remove the `?xxx=` then split it again by `,` to finally have an array with the stuff you're looking at.

```js
var str = "?pn1=age&pn2=name&pv1=12&pv2=alice";
var split = str.split('&').toString().replace(/([?]?[pnv0-9]+[=])/g,'').split(',');

console.log(split[0] + ':' + split[2] + '|' + split[1] + ':' + split[3]);
```

**EDIT :** worth mentioning for those who are looking to the best performing solution, I tested all those provided here, click [here](https://jsbench.me/2vjwhpyu2l/1) for more infos.

The solution's list from the fastest to the slowest :

- **Maheer Ali** (113,610 ops/s ±1.48% fastest)
- **tcj** (112,324 ops/s ±1.01% 1.13% slower)
- **Nina Scholz** (81,067 ops/s ±1.81% 28.64% slower)
- **Code Maniac** (80,074 ops/s ±0.99% 29.52% slower)
- **adiga** (33,065 ops/s ±0.92% 70.9% slower)